# WPF: how to change my chart to get only one value instead of 2

Tags: wpf, charts

This is my `chart`:

```
<Grid>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Name="lineChart" Margin="16,90,30,483" Background="Transparent">
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key"
         ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSelectionEnabled="True" Margin="0,-37,0,37" >
            <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineSeries">
                    <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">
                        <Polyline x:Name="polyline"
                                  Points="{TemplateBinding Points}" 
                                  Stroke="Yellow" 
                                  Style="{TemplateBinding PolylineStyle}" />
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Template>
        </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

Currently i am using this `list` to populate my `chart`:

```
ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, int>> points
```

But after change my model i have only 1 `value` that i want to add - `double` so i try to remove from my `chart` the `DependentValuePath="Value"` or `IndependentValuePath="Key"` but this likely not the way to do that.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the `LineSeries.ItemsSource` is databound to the `ObservableCollection`. In that case, you should be able to edit the collection like this `points.Remove(pairToRemove)` and the chart should update itself.

Comment: it will not be more simple to define my collection with only one value ?

Comment: It is probably more simple to start a new chart, with a new data binding than to try to retrofit the existing one by manually editing the corresponding XAML.